# CSS3 transition glitch in Chrome

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I have a simple modal, which opens up upon :checked input. In Firefox and IE the transition animation works fine, but in Chrome it glitches (effect not smooth) when it shows up upon checking the input.

Demo fiddle: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s8hts3v7/1/)

When i remove `visibility: hidden` it works fine, but then the modal blocks the rest of the page under neath it - no text can be selected, no buttons clicked etc.

Any ideas on how to make the transition smooth in Chrome?

Comment: It seems to be working fine in my chrome?

Comment: where are you applying `visibility: none`? do you mean `visibility: hidden`?

Comment: @Mr_Green yes, thx - i have edited my question.

Comment: @Grumpy Strange, i have exact setup localy and initial transition upon opening the modal has this glitch in Chrome.

Comment: what do you mean with glitch? That the transition isn't smooth, with a short stop in between the animation or something else?

Comment: @marczking I think he meant the same. I can see the same stop effect here.

Comment: @g5wx check my below answer.

Comment: @g5wx does my answer solve your issue?

Comment: @marczking Yep, it does :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Answer

You declared `transform: none;` on your modal `div`. Just define a rotationX instead, so your animation has a starting and ending point. That solves the animation issue:

```
input#switch:checked ~ #test > div {
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s8hts3v7/9/

#### Code Snippet

```css
#test {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  z-index: 9999999;
  visibility: hidden;
}
input#switch:checked ~ #test {
  visibility: visible;
}
#test > div {
  background: #fff;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  transform: perspective(300px) rotateX(-90deg);
  transform-origin: top center;
  transition: 0.4s ease;
}
input#switch:checked ~ #test > div {
  transform: rotateX(0deg);
}
#test > div label {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<input id="switch" type="checkbox" name="test-chkbox" />
<label for="switch">Open modal</label>

<div id="test">
    <div>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
    <label for="switch">Close modal</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27900053/1577396), we can't use `visibility` to animate. So, instead I used `opacity` passing as `rgba` value to background.

```css
    #test {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
        z-index: -1;
    }
    input#switch:checked ~ #test {
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
        z-index: 9999999;
    }
    #test > div {
        background: #fff;
        width: 300px;
        height: 100px;
        padding: 30px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        margin: auto;
        transform: perspective(300px) rotateX(-90deg);
        transform-origin: top center;
        transition: 0.4s ease;
    }
    input#switch:checked ~ #test > div {
        transform: none;
    }
    #test > div label {
        background: #000;
        color: #fff;
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 8px;
        margin-top: 20px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
```

```html
<input id="switch" type="checkbox" name="test-chkbox" />
<label for="switch">Open modal</label>
<div id="test">
    <div>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
        <label for="switch">Close modal</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I also tried your approach, but the problem with your answer is, although you solve the animation issue, you get a `click` issue. If you open the modal and want to `close` it, you sometimes have to click **twice**. Sometimes the first click doesn't trigger the closing

Comment: Thx Mr_Green, i know i cant animate visibility, i was looking for a workaround for the current setup.

Answer (score 0):

Please check fiddle: [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/yoshicn/tp27novm/1/)

Just added:

```
opacity: 0.01;
z-index: -1;
```

to #test, and changing z-index + opacity when overlay showing:

```
opacity: 0.99;
z-index: 9999999;
```

Comment: thx for your input but the transition upon closing the modal doesnt work now.