# How to conditionally show an element, keeping its occupied space?

Tags: css, vue.js

Vue.js has two conditional keywords: [`v-if` and `v-show`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html) which allow for an element to be visible or not based on a condition. The difference is

> The difference is that an element with `v-show` will always be
> rendered and remain in the DOM; `v-show` only toggles the display CSS
> property of the element.

I thought that it would have an impact on the space taken by an invisible element but in any of these cases, the space occupied by an element is none when the condition is false.

This means that in, say, a span of three elements taking 100% of the width of the screen, the place of the invisible is taken by the next one, as in this example with CSS Grid:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    visible: true
  },
  mounted() {
    setInterval(() => this.visible = !this.visible, 1000)
  }
})
```

```css
#app {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
}

#app div {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>one</div>
  <div v-if="visible">two</div>
  <div>three</div>
</div>
```

**Is there a simple way to hide the contents of the element (making it invisible), but keep its space?**
(to have, in the example above, the central element appearing and disappearing - but with the two other ones not moving)

Comment: You'd probably have to set a fixed width on the inner element or use `display: flex` with justify content between.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See [MDN - CSS visibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility),

> The visibility CSS property can show or hide an element without affecting the layout of a document (i.e., space is created for elements regardless of whether they are visible or not)

So, use [Vue's dynamic style](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Binding-Inline-Styles) to bind your expression to CSS visibility.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    visible: true
  },
  mounted() {
    setInterval(() => this.visible = !this.visible, 1000)
  }
})
```

```css
#app {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
}

#app div {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>one</div>
  <div :style="{visibility: visible ? 'visible' : 'hidden'}">two</div>
  <div>three</div>
  {{visible}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 14):

Look at this: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/vue-style-visibility-hidden-on-v-show-how/58293

You can achieve it, using a custom directive:

```
Vue.directive('visible', function(el, binding) {
    el.style.visibility = !!binding.value ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
});
```

And then use

```
<div v-visible="your_condition" ... >
```

Comment: I was going to bind a style, then I saw this.  I didn't even know about this.  Very nice, elegant solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to trigger `vue transitions`.

Answer (score 6):

bind style with opacity = 0 or 1.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    visible: true
  },
  mounted() {
    setInterval(() => this.visible = !this.visible, 1000)
  }
})
```

```css
.layout {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
}

.your-column {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="layout">
    <div class="your-column">one</div>
    <div class="your-column" :style="{'opacity':visible?1:0}">two</div>
    <div class="your-column">three</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    visible: true
  },
  mounted() {
    setInterval(() => this.visible = !this.visible, 1000)
  }
})
```

```css
#app {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

#app div {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1;
}

#app div:last-child{
  grid-column:3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>one</div>
  <div v-if="visible">two</div>
  <div>three</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to Max' answer and to address Artur's comment about transitions, here is a way to incorporate a simple transition into the directive.

```js
Vue.directive('visible', function(el, binding) {
  el.style.visibility = !!bindung.value ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
  el.style.opacity = !!binding.value ? 1 : 0;
  el.style.cssText += 'transition: visibility 0.3s linear, opacity 0.3s linear;'
});
```

Mind the `+=` instead of `=` for the `cssText` property, to avoid overriding the whole style.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29318542/6608142) as a reference, and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27900094/6608142) as the reason why visibiliy can't be animated as a standalone style.

#### Example

```js
<template>
  <div @mouseover="showText = true" @mouseleave="showText = false">
    <p v-visible="showText">Some random text</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';
const showText = ref(false);
</script>
```