# How to set visibility:hidden then visibility:visible in a CSS animation?

Tags: jquery, css

**Edit 3** Actually, I didn't need to be messing with the visibility/ opacity at all... so I removed those lines (as shown in edit 2)... added animation-play-state: paused/ running....

Got the effect I wanted...

---

**Edit 2**: Thanks Gineto for the idea! Made some changes (see below):

```
.logos2{
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    height:100%;
    right:75px;
    animation: move 1s;
    animation-play-state:paused;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

and in jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery(".logos").animate({height: +800}, 500);
    jQuery(".logos").promise().done(function(){
      jQuery(".logos2").css({"animation-play-state":"running"});
    });
});
```

---

**Edit**: Have come somewhat close by changing jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery(".logos").animate({height: +800}, 500);
    jQuery(".logos").promise().done(function(){
      jQuery(".logos1").addClass('logos2');
    });

  });
```

but adding a class dynamically shift are logo a lot...

---

I want my CSS animation to be hidden at first (letting another animation run) then after to have the initial animation to be visible.

Here is my CSS code:

```
.logos{    
    position: absolute;
    width:100vw;
    margin:0 auto;
    height:0vh;
    bottom: 0;
}
.logos1{

    position: relative;
    float: right;
    height:100%;
    top: 100px;
    right:75px;
    visibility: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

@keyframes move{
    0%{right:-100px;}
    50%{right:90px;visibility: hidden;}
    100%{right:75px;visibility: visible}
}


.logos2{

    position: relative;
    float: right;
    height:100%;
    top: 100px;
    right:75px;
    animation: move 1.5s; 
    animation-delay: 1s;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

and my jQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery(".logos").animate({height: +800}, 500);
    jQuery(".logos1").height(100);
    jQuery(".logos1").promise().done(function(){
      jQuery(".logos1").addClass('logos2');
      jQuery(".logos2").removeClass('logos1');     
      jQuery(".logos2").promise().done(function(){
      jQuery(".logos2").css('visibilty','visible');
      })
    })
  });
```

what happens when I run the jquery is that the animation is visible at start...

Anyone know how to resolve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try transitioning the opacity from 0 to 1.

See: [CSS transition with visibility not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27900053/css-transition-with-visibility-not-working) for more details