# CSS Transition: opacity and visibility transition not working on Firefox (works on Chrome / Safari)

Tags: html, css, transition

I am trying to create a transition on a full screen overlay that is full width and full height with nonactive styles of `visibility: hidden` and `opacity: 0`. When clicking on a hamburger icon, an `.active` class is added to the div and it has the following styles: `visibility: visible` and `opacity: 1`.

Here is the CSS:

```
  .overlay {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: '#272727';
    z-index: 100;
    transition: visibility 500ms ease, opacity 500ms ease;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    &.active {
      visibility: visible;
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
```

The transition is occurring as expected on Chrome and Safari but the "fade-in" part of the transition fails on Firefox. It's basically skipping from the first frame to the last frame without transitioning. Here is a link to the page if you want to see it in action: [link to webpage](http://dboxcg.dev.dbox.com/portfolio)

And a video of what is occurring if you are unable to replicate the issue on your browser [screen recording](https://s3.amazonaws.com/dboxcg.dev.dbox.com/Screen+Recording+2020-04-17+at+4.44.50+PM.mov):

Why is this transition not working on Firefox?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this is due to when the visibility is changed in the transition and seems to display inconsistently between browsers.

This demonstrates your code and for me in Firefox if you toggle the element quickly it does not transition smoothly. This is always how I've done similar transitions and only recently started noticing the problem.

```js
var element = document.querySelector(".element")
var toggle = document.querySelector(".element-toggle")

toggle.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  element.classList.toggle("active");
});
```

```css
.element{
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: opacity 500ms ease, visibility 500ms ease;
}

.element.active{
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="element">This is a div element</div>

<button type="button" class="element-toggle">Toggle</button>
```

After reviewing, this is what works for me:

```js
var element = document.querySelector(".element")
var toggle = document.querySelector(".element-toggle")

toggle.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  element.classList.toggle("active");
});
```

```css
.element{
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: opacity 500ms ease, visibility 0s ease 500ms;
}

.element.active{
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transition: opacity 500ms ease, visibility 0s ease 0s;
}
```

```html
<div class="element">This is a div element</div>

<button type="button" class="element-toggle">Toggle</button>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Nice answer. In the future or in this answer, you can also use [code snippet option](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/356679/10892074) to add live code to your answer! It will make a life a lot easier for future visitors and for OP him/herself.

Comment: Tested your code in Firefox. After 1 or 2 clicks - the same issues started. Fading up without transition.

Comment: @focus.style, that's strange. I've added both the snippets to the answer and just looked at them both in Firefox. Seems to be showing first the issue and then the solution working correctly for me.

Comment: Indeed. Second one woks stable.

Comment: I wish we knew why some browsers have broken the ability to animate the 'visibility' property. If anyone finds anything out please let us know!

Comment: @Moucky could you please move the solution UP in the answer ? It kind of appears that the solution is the issue example at start :)

Answer (score 2):

Seems like visibility doesn't have transition options. So the transition works incorrect.

In **.bbfIaB** this part

```
transition: visibility 500ms ease 0s, opacity 500ms ease 0s;
```

Change to this

```
transition: opacity 500ms ease 0s;
```

**UPDATED**

The best solution in this situation will be next:

1. Removing visibility from transition in CSS.
2. Removing `visibility: hidden;` from `.bbfIaB`
3. Add new css class, like `.hidden {visibility: hidden;}`
4. Add a JavaScript, which will add `.hidden` 500ms after removing `.active`
5. Class `.hidden` should be added to the template by default, should be removed with activation of class `.active`

---

**UPDATE 2**

Working example without `visibility` transition at all.

```js
var element = document.querySelector(".element")
var toggle = document.querySelector(".element-toggle")

toggle.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  if (element.classList.contains("active")) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      element.style.visibility = '';
    }, 500);    
  } else {
    element.style.visibility = 'visible';
  }  
  element.classList.toggle("active");
});
```

```css
.element{
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: opacity 500ms ease;
}

.element.active{
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="element">This is a div element</div>
<button type="button" class="element-toggle">Toggle</button>
```

Comment: According to the accepted answer from this post you can transition the visibility property: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331353/transitions-on-the-css-display-property?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top

Comment: This accepted answer tells the other point. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27900053/css-transition-with-visibility-not-working

Comment: Yeah, i see, the visibility in now on the accepted list. But it works incorrect in Firefox and we can't do anything with it for now. Updated the answer with te possible solution.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties

Comment: If it's in the documentation as an animatable property then what gives? I am fairly certain that previous versions of FF have been able to animate opacity/visibility.

Comment: Yeah. i See, now it is in documentation. Interesting that with and without console it works different way in FF. I think, int's FF bug. I suggest to abstain of using visibility. Updated my answer yesterday with some recommendations .

Comment: Illustrated the idea of my answer in code. Working without visibility transition but with correct set or `visibility` after animation.