# Create a show / hide transition with Tailwind and Next

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

Is there any way to create a display or visibility transition using Tailwind and a conditional code at Next? I'm trying something like this, what I would like to achieve is a smooth fade in effect when the backend returns a exception message under the responseError object (using Context in Next) but there's no transition effect at all:

```
{
  responseError ?
    <span className={`${ responseError ? "visible transition-all ease-in-out delay-150 duration-300" : "invisible"} pt-4 text-sm text-red-500 font-['Poppins'] font-bold `}>
       username or password incorrect
     </span>
  : null
 }
```

or

```
{
  responseError ?
    <span className={`${ responseError ? "visible transition-all ease-in-out delay-150 duration-300" : "invisible"} pt-4 text-sm text-red-500 font-['Poppins'] font-bold `}>
       { responseError.message }
    </span>
  : null
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `opacity` instead of `visibility`.

[This stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27900094/20913924) goes over a similar issue you are facing. In short, the `visibility` property has two possible values: visible or hidden. On the other hand, `opacity` can be between 0 and 1, so proper keyframes can be applied when using the `transition` property.

As a side note, I noticed you are checking for the `responseError` twice, once to render the `<span>` and again to apply tailwind classes. This will cause your fade in transition to only work when fading in because the `<span>` is only rendered when `responseError` exists. Instead, try something like this:

```
<span className={`${ responseError ? "opacity-100" : "opacity-0"} transition-opacity ease-in-out delay-150 duration-300 pt-4 text-sm text-red-500 font-['Poppins'] font-bold `}>
   { responseError ? responseError.message : '' }
</span>
```

Comment: This is a good answer, thought I would add, the opacity-0 element is still going to get in the way on your layout, whereas the hidden class gives you that space back as it's display:none. 

That means if you want to use opacity-0 to 100 transitions for slideshows and the likes, you will have to use absolute positioning to overlay anything and handle any widths/heights some other way.

Comment: @JohnLewis that's a valid concern that can be easily handled by adding Tailwind's `invisible` and `visible` classes.